# How can I get this <h1> element to appear under the tables instead of to the right of it?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML with 2 horizontally aligned `<tables>` with a `<h1>` underneath. The `<h1>` element isn't rendering correctly though; it's appearing to the right of the tables instead of under them. How can I get it to appear under the tables?

This is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w3LWC/1/

and the HTML for reference:

```
<div class="horizontal-div-container">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th >Panel ID:</th><th>100721651</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th >RFI Points:</th><th>0</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th >Panel ID:</th><th>100721651</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th >RFI Points:</th><th>0</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table> 
    </div>
</div>

<h1>PANEL CONFIGURATION</h1>

.horizontal-div-container div {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: add `h1{clear:left}` - http://jsfiddle.net/w3LWC/7/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `clear: both` on your h1 element:

http://jsfiddle.net/w3LWC/2/

```
.horizontal-div-container div {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
h1{
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create one more css tag in your css File i.e. h1{clear:both}. you can add this code in your css and the your  element apper under the tables.

Answer (score 0):

In your css add this,

`h1
{
clear: both;
}`

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. You just need to apply a `clear:left;` to the `<h1>`.

As your style `.horizontal-div-container div` has a `float:left;` which is preventing it to move down.

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w3LWC/6/)**

**The Code:**

```
<h1 style="clear:left;">PANEL CONFIGURATION</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/esisov/2/edit)

Set CSS class to **h1** tag, declare it as clear.

```
h1{
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `clear:both` to `h1` ,
Try the below css

```
h1{clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.horizontal-div-container {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

See also [Clearing floats on QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).